# How can I update / re-render a list in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have tried using useState (which is what the commented out lines are from) but I would get an error of "too many re-renders." The list updates correctly but the component is not updated on the screen. I can't figure out how to get react to update the data in render though. I also tried using UseState but it kept erroring out. I am new to react so i'm kind of lost on how to do this.

The code here is supposed to update the calendar days when the arrows are pressed but even though the list[] is updated, list.map isn't called again in render() to update this.

```
    function App() {

  var currentMonth = 0;
  var months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  var monthNames = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  //const [list, updateList] = useState([]);
  var list = [];

  var monthName;
  //var copyList

  const startCalender = (month) => {

    //copyList = [];
    list = [];
    monthName = monthNames[month];

    for (let day = 0; day < months[month]; day++) {
      //copyList.push(<div>Day: {day + 1}</div>
      list.push(<div>Day: {day + 1}</div>
      )}}

      //updateList(copyList);

  startCalender(currentMonth);

  const changeMonth = (changeAmount) => {
    currentMonth += changeAmount;

    if(currentMonth > 11) currentMonth = 0
    else if(currentMonth < 0) currentMonth = 12;

    console.log("here1");

    startCalender(currentMonth);
  }

  const initalizeVariables = () => {
     document.querySelector(".leftArrow").addEventListener('click', () => {
       changeMonth(-1);
     });
     document.querySelector(".rightArrow").addEventListener('click', () => {
       changeMonth(1);
     });
  }

  window.onload = initalizeVariables;
   
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
        <BiLeftArrowAlt className="arrowIcon leftArrow"/>
        <div>{monthName}</div>
        <BiRightArrowAlt className="arrowIcon rightArrow"/>
      </div>
      <div className = "daysContainer">
        {list.map((data) => {
          return <IndividualDay info={data}/>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I’m not even sure what this is supposed to do. but this is not how to bind handlers or to use state. Did you do the tutorial to begin with? If you are using `document.querySelector` to query Dom nodes that are rendered by react you are doing something wrong almost certainly. Unfortunately the official tutorial is not really up to date but there are some other good ones using hooks as well.

Comment: Can you provide more information that what you are trying to display? Also querySelector doesn't work here. One more thing, don't ever use ```var```, use ```const```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  const monthNames = [
    "January",
    "Febuary",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ];

  const [theList, setTheList] = useState([]);
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(0);

  let monthName;
  //var copyList

  const startCalender = (month) => {
    const list = [];
    monthName = monthNames[month];

    for (let day = 0; day < months[month]; day++) {
      //copyList.push(<div>Day: {day + 1}</div>
      list.push(<div>Day: {day + 1}</div>);
    }
    setTheList(list);
  };

  const changeMonth = (changeAmount) => {
    let theCurrentMonth = currentMonth;
    theCurrentMonth += changeAmount;
    if (theCurrentMonth > 11) theCurrentMonth = 0;
    else if (theCurrentMonth < 0) theCurrentMonth = 12;

    setCurrentMonth( theCurrentMonth );
    startCalender(theCurrentMonth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    startCalender(currentMonth);
  }, []);

  return (
      <div className="App">
  <div className="header">
    <div onClick={() => changeMonth(-1)}>
      <BiLeftArrowAlt className="arrowIcon leftArrow"/>
    </div>
    <div>{monthName}</div>
    <div onClick={() => changeMonth(1)}>
      <BiRightArrowAlt className="arrowIcon leftArrow"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="daysContainer">
    {theList.map((data) => {
      return <IndividualDay info={data}/>;
    })}
  </div>
</div>
  );
}
```

Please try to code in React like so as well.

So the first problem that comes to the eye is that instead of useEffect, you used onload. Try to use useEffect in React.

The second issue is, using querySelectors where you should be assigning functions as the code shows. Thats the beauty of JSX.

The third major problem is when you say `var list = [];` in the code, your basically redoing this line every render. So if you want a state or variable to stay constant through renders and which you can manipulate, use useState or useRef.

The fourth minor problem is, try switching from var to const or let.

Comment: I ran it but got the same "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." from React.

Comment: Please add the IndividualDay component to your code. The problme must be in there. Make sure to put the setState outside of the part of the code that gets rerendered all the time.

Comment: @AminDarian You should edit your answer to include a description of what you changed rather than just posting a big code snippet with no context.

Comment: @jharris711 I first want to make sure the problem is solved, then Ill put the time to explain what was wrong with the code.

Comment: The IndividualDay is imported correctly, i'm not sure how useEffect is supposed to be used though. In the original code, it would run without errors and using console.log i could see the list updating its value but the .map function inside render() wasn't running when the list updated.

Comment: @LucasDowlen I want you to delete the IndividualDay component and see if the error occures. Its not about the importing its about setting states correctly. Inside list map just return console lot index.

Comment: yes, the error still occurs without the IndividualDay component.

Comment: @AminDarian if it helps, removing setTheList(list) removes the error

Comment: Im debuging it as we speak. You need the state as basically giving a const in the code where you have put it, would assign [] to the list every time it renders.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, do you want me to move the line setTheList to a more stable location?

Comment: I updated the code if this doesnt work for I dont know what elese to do hosenstly.

Comment: It runs without errors but the {data} isn't getting passed to IndividualDay. Its improvement though and thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @LucasDowlen Yeah the details Ill be correcting but overall if it  works thats good to know. BTW if you can select this as the selected answer cause so far I lost one reputation lol. Up to you though.

Comment: @LucasDowlen Appreciate your help as well :)

Comment: @Amin Darian Just wanted to say I fixed the last of the issues and it completely works now. I was working on this for like 6 hours. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @LucasDowlen No problem. Try to read the whole React docs if you havent already. I know its frustrating but it would payoff.